# Unable to connect google glass

Tags: google-glass

I am trying to connect my google glass to my system but every time I connect it is being recognized as **Android ADB Interface** under **Android Devices** in the Device Manager (Screenshot attached).
Due to this i am not able to run my applications as it doesn't show up in the Device Picker of Android studio.

I tried connecting it to my friends system and it worked fine on that. But the only difference i noticed was that the device was being shown as **Android Composite Device Interface** under the **Android Devices** in the Device Manager.
I have already tried a fix to alter my android_winusb.inf and insert some custom lines but that also dint worked.

Can anyone else help me with some other solution?
[image: Computer Management]

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you aren't getting enough power on that USB hub.